# MySql crashing with Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

Everynow and then, I have my MySQL database crashing on my Ubuntu server and not recovering automatically. I have then to reboot the instance of AWS.
When I look at the database logfile, I see a 'Cannot allocate memory' and a bit a bit later 'Aborting'.
Not sure what I need to do to get this fixed.

[image: enter code here]

When we noticed the problem, we rebooted the instance at 2020-09-05T02:25:00 and database server was up again. However it complained about tables being marked as crashed, but all those tables are working just fine.

```html
2020-09-05T02:01:51.561746Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2020-09-05T02:25:17.349636Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2020-09-05T02:25:17.349731Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2020-09-05T02:25:17.365104Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) starting as process 1169 ...
2020-09-05T02:25:17.400286Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2020-09-05T02:25:17.400311Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-09-05T02:25:17.400316Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-09-05T02:25:17.400320Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2020-09-05T02:25:17.400324Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-09-05T02:25:17.400331Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-09-05T02:25:17.402889Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-09-05T02:25:17.426116Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-09-05T02:25:17.429145Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-09-05T02:25:17.478522Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-09-05T02:25:17.501421Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-09-05T02:25:17.526217Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-09-05T02:25:17.537683Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 159706950835
2020-09-05T02:25:17.537708Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 159706964288
2020-09-05T02:25:17.553664Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2020-09-05T02:25:17.553682Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2020-09-05T02:25:17.780803Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 6 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up in total 3 row operations to undo
2020-09-05T02:25:17.780836Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Trx id counter is 181906176
2020-09-05T02:25:17.780870Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
2020-09-05T02:25:17.810466Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Apply batch completed
2020-09-05T02:25:19.508086Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of uncommitted transactions
2020-09-05T02:25:19.508121Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 181905778, 1 rows to undo
2020-09-05T02:25:19.509650Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-09-05T02:25:19.510701Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-09-05T02:25:19.510746Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-09-05T02:25:19.514124Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 181905778 completed
2020-09-05T02:25:19.514138Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 181905777, 0 rows to undo
2020-09-05T02:25:19.516052Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 181905777 completed
2020-09-05T02:25:19.516067Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 181905776, 0 rows to undo
2020-09-05T02:25:19.517962Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 181905776 completed
2020-09-05T02:25:19.517976Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 181905775, 1 rows to undo
2020-09-05T02:25:19.518524Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 181905775 completed
2020-09-05T02:25:19.518535Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 181905774, 0 rows to undo
2020-09-05T02:25:19.519119Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 181905774 completed
2020-09-05T02:25:19.519130Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 181905773, 1 rows to undo
2020-09-05T02:25:19.519892Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 181905773 completed
2020-09-05T02:25:19.519903Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of non-prepared transactions completed
2020-09-05T02:25:19.547465Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-09-05T02:25:19.548328Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-09-05T02:25:19.548340Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-09-05T02:25:19.548590Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-09-05T02:25:19.598820Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.27 started; log sequence number 159706964288
2020-09-05T02:25:19.599054Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-09-05T02:25:19.599950Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2020-09-05T02:25:19.614936Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2020-09-05T02:25:19.614952Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
2020-09-05T02:25:19.614962Z 0 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
2020-09-05T02:25:19.615054Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2020-09-05T02:25:19.695356Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2020-09-05T02:25:19.695517Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
2020-09-05T02:25:19.722606Z 2 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './aa24serv_db/configurations' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:25:19.730821Z 2 [Warning] Checking table:   './aa24serv_db/configurations'
2020-09-05T02:25:20.267555Z 7 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/driversposition_697' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:25:20.267723Z 7 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/driversposition_697'
2020-09-05T02:25:20.873826Z 12 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/driversposition_331' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:25:20.874013Z 12 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/driversposition_331'
2020-09-05T02:25:20.907543Z 7 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/drivers_697' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:25:20.907732Z 7 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/drivers_697'
2020-09-05T02:25:21.689884Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200905  2:25:21
2020-09-05T02:25:22.776956Z 60 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/driversposition_326' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:25:22.777151Z 60 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/driversposition_326'
2020-09-05T02:25:23.395891Z 70 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/driversposition_1017' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:25:23.396055Z 70 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/driversposition_1017'
2020-09-05T02:25:24.277092Z 83 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/driversposition_1152' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:25:24.277251Z 83 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/driversposition_1152'
2020-09-05T02:25:25.839272Z 105 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/driversposition_696' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:25:25.839504Z 105 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/driversposition_696'
2020-09-05T02:25:28.798740Z 60 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/drivers_326' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:25:28.798915Z 60 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/drivers_326'
2020-09-05T02:25:29.887995Z 136 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/driversposition_971' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:25:29.888173Z 136 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/driversposition_971'
2020-09-05T02:25:30.579270Z 105 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/drivers_696' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:25:30.579465Z 105 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/drivers_696'
2020-09-05T02:25:34.177069Z 163 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/driversposition_695' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:25:34.177263Z 163 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/driversposition_695'
2020-09-05T02:25:35.020548Z 159 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/drivers_331' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:25:35.020833Z 159 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/drivers_331'
2020-09-05T02:25:35.224829Z 136 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/drivers_971' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:25:35.225016Z 136 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/drivers_971'
2020-09-05T02:25:36.024503Z 163 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/drivers_695' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:25:36.024741Z 163 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/drivers_695'
2020-09-05T02:25:38.027276Z 181 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/driversposition_1143' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:25:38.027464Z 181 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/driversposition_1143'
2020-09-05T02:25:41.857276Z 160 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/drivers_1017' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:25:41.858227Z 160 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/drivers_1017'
2020-09-05T02:25:43.924977Z 211 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/subscripiphone' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:25:43.925136Z 211 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/subscripiphone'
2020-09-05T02:25:44.368602Z 215 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/subscripandroid' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:25:44.368754Z 215 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/subscripandroid'
2020-09-05T02:25:44.518414Z 215 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/simullog' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:25:44.518557Z 215 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/simullog'
2020-09-05T02:25:44.536079Z 215 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/requestA41' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:25:44.536210Z 215 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/requestA41'
2020-09-05T02:25:45.005557Z 215 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/getbackA41' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:25:45.005720Z 215 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/getbackA41'
2020-09-05T02:25:47.147724Z 215 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/errorA41' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:25:47.147943Z 215 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/errorA41'
2020-09-05T02:25:55.709984Z 290 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/request71' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:25:55.710131Z 290 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/request71'
2020-09-05T02:25:55.834131Z 290 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/getback71' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:25:55.834285Z 290 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/getback71'
2020-09-05T02:25:58.890684Z 290 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/error71' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:25:58.891293Z 290 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/error71'
2020-09-05T02:26:01.030821Z 181 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/drivers_1143' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:26:01.030893Z 242 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/drivers_1143' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:26:01.031055Z 181 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/drivers_1143'
2020-09-05T02:27:01.787645Z 626 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/mtcl_1017' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:27:01.789989Z 626 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/mtcl_1017'
2020-09-05T02:27:04.699328Z 641 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/mtcl_tripn_1017' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:27:04.699491Z 641 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/mtcl_tripn_1017'
2020-09-05T02:27:28.700579Z 775 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/mtcl_696' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:27:28.700776Z 775 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/mtcl_696'
2020-09-05T02:29:19.918869Z 1330 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/mtcl_1152' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:29:19.921199Z 1330 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/mtcl_1152'
2020-09-05T02:29:21.672286Z 1340 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/mtcl_tripn_1152' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:29:21.672442Z 1340 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/mtcl_tripn_1152'
2020-09-05T02:30:41.743038Z 1751 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/mtcl_1143' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:30:41.743245Z 1751 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/mtcl_1143'
2020-09-05T02:30:43.520680Z 1751 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/mtcl_tripn_1143' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:30:43.521162Z 1751 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/mtcl_tripn_1143'
2020-09-05T02:30:58.728673Z 1837 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/mtcl_1372' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:30:58.728906Z 1837 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/mtcl_1372'
2020-09-05T02:30:58.734697Z 1837 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/mtcl_tripn_1372' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:30:58.734830Z 1837 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/mtcl_tripn_1372'
2020-09-05T02:31:01.796568Z 1862 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/drivers_903' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:31:01.796782Z 1862 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/drivers_903'
2020-09-05T02:31:31.083242Z 2011 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/mtcl_499' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:31:31.083439Z 2011 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/mtcl_499'
2020-09-05T02:31:31.987881Z 2015 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/mtcl_tripn_499' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:31:31.988031Z 2015 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/mtcl_tripn_499'
2020-09-05T02:31:56.364430Z 2148 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/mtcl_906' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:31:56.364684Z 2148 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/mtcl_906'
2020-09-05T02:36:06.012382Z 3421 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/driversposition_589' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:36:06.013041Z 3421 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/driversposition_589'
2020-09-05T02:36:06.104535Z 3421 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/drivers_589' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:36:06.104698Z 3421 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/drivers_589'
2020-09-05T02:47:09.410637Z 6569 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/mtcl_tripn_906' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:47:09.411825Z 6569 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/mtcl_tripn_906'
2020-09-05T02:48:53.691118Z 7105 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/drivers_1276' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:48:53.691463Z 7105 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/drivers_1276'
2020-09-05T02:51:29.926090Z 7886 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/mtcl_tripn_696' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:51:29.926651Z 7886 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/mtcl_tripn_696'
2020-09-05T02:51:34.462126Z 7920 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/mtcl_695' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:51:34.462473Z 7920 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/mtcl_695'
2020-09-05T02:53:15.756119Z 8421 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/mtcl_tripn_695' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T02:53:15.756721Z 8421 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/mtcl_tripn_695'
2020-09-05T03:06:21.094191Z 12114 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/drivers_424' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T03:06:21.097786Z 12114 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/drivers_424'
2020-09-05T03:09:58.065719Z 13116 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/mtcl_424' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T03:09:58.066597Z 13116 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/mtcl_424'
2020-09-05T03:09:58.121514Z 13116 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/mtcl_tripn_424' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T03:09:58.121659Z 13116 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/mtcl_tripn_424'
2020-09-05T03:40:05.777802Z 20790 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/mtcl_593' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T03:40:05.780686Z 20790 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/mtcl_593'
2020-09-05T03:40:06.462583Z 20802 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/mtcl_tripn_593' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T03:40:06.462731Z 20802 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/mtcl_tripn_593'
2020-09-05T03:44:00.801393Z 21806 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/mtcl_697' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T03:44:00.808918Z 21806 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/mtcl_697'
2020-09-05T03:44:02.578377Z 21806 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/mtcl_tripn_697' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T03:44:02.578545Z 21806 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/mtcl_tripn_697'
2020-09-05T03:49:40.447680Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2020-09-05T03:49:40.447868Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2020-09-05T03:49:40.449966Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) starting as process 5835 ...
2020-09-05T03:49:40.457339Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2020-09-05T03:49:40.457366Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-09-05T03:49:40.457378Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-09-05T03:49:40.457383Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2020-09-05T03:49:40.457387Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-09-05T03:49:40.457394Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-09-05T03:49:40.458390Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-09-05T03:49:40.468945Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-09-05T03:49:40.473666Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-09-05T03:49:40.487299Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-09-05T03:49:40.492814Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-09-05T03:49:40.549744Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-09-05T03:49:40.588299Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 159720001331
2020-09-05T03:49:40.588331Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 159720013083
2020-09-05T03:49:40.631301Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2020-09-05T03:49:40.631321Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2020-09-05T03:49:41.146974Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
2020-09-05T03:49:41.170217Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Apply batch completed
2020-09-05T03:49:43.255505Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-09-05T03:49:43.255769Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-09-05T03:49:43.255816Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-09-05T03:49:43.292793Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-09-05T03:49:43.293918Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-09-05T03:49:43.293930Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-09-05T03:49:43.294268Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-09-05T03:49:43.344863Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.27 started; log sequence number 159720013083
2020-09-05T03:49:43.345121Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-09-05T03:49:43.347247Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2020-09-05T03:49:43.379594Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2020-09-05T03:49:43.379621Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
2020-09-05T03:49:43.379632Z 0 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
2020-09-05T03:49:43.379662Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2020-09-05T03:49:43.522185Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2020-09-05T03:49:43.522500Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
2020-09-05T03:49:43.545359Z 2 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mtc_app/driversposition_697' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-05T03:49:43.560097Z 2 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/driversposition_697'
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have enough free Memory to fit the innodb_buffer_pool_size

So you can increase the memory in your server or you reduce the parameter till it fits your
system in the mysql.ini/cnf file. For example 100 MB like shown

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=100M
```

Comment: ok, that explains why the restart crashes. But why does MySql restart at all in the first place since it has been running for hours without problem? Has it something to do with the page_cleaner message, or the 2 warning just below them? Any entries in the logfile before my screenshot are more than 2 hours old, but contain multiple worrying error messages, like: 
Table './mtc_app/t_area_map_audit' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-09-04T23:50:48.165175Z 15502 [Warning] Checking table:   './mtc_app/t_area_map_audit'. But those tables are just fine!

Comment: you shpuld have posted those also, check further the system logs it sounds like it is quite unstable

Comment: I have added logfile from after aws instance was rebooted

Comment: you must run mysqlcheck -A --auto-repair from the sheöll, one of the crashes produced errors.

Comment: How much RAM does your server have available?